# Is there a straightforward and general way to wrap a scala object's code with code to be executed before and after the object body code?

Tags: scala, traits

I am trying to create some general functionality which allows me to add code to be executed before and after the body of a Scala object (extended with the App trait) in a generic way - something akin to Scalatest's BeforeAndAfterAll but for general code execution.

I would love to figure out a way to do this via a trait but am coming up short - something like

```
trait MyBeforeAndAfter {
    def before = println("I am executed before!")
    def after = println("I am executed after!")
}


object MyApp extends App with MyBeforeAndAfter {
    println("I am generic code in the body that's wrapped") 
}
```

and the target output when running the App would be (key feature being the ordering):

```
I am executed before
I am generic code in the body that's wrapped
I am executed after
```

Two approaches I have considered but can't figure out how to do are:

1. Somehow pass the code in the object body to a function which takes care of the wrapping - but I don't know how I can get access to the code block as something which I could pass to a function. I have looked at both the App trait itself and Scalatest's BeforeAndAfterAll to see their approaches. The former appears to be controlled in the compiler. The latter, I'm in the fifth level of inception and it's not yet clear to me how it works.
2. Split the before and after into separate traits and mix them in, and while trait ordering is pretty straightforward, I don't see any way to annotate that a trait should be executed after the base / target object / class.

Gods of Stack Overflow... help?

Edit per Luis' question - basically why do you want to do this?
I was working with akka quite a bit to build recently and with akka there's a lot of ActorSystem setup / teardown boilerplate - grabbing things from configs, standing up the system etc and I was thinking of ways to clear out some of that boilerplate to make the unique parts of the main app more visible. I ran into some similar desires in some other contexts as well and I continued to think about whether there was a general way to clear out the boilerplate in a "clean" manner - meaning similar to the App trait (no overrides required, just mixin and go), but also enabling flexibility to execute code both before and after the block.

Comment: It would also good to explain why you need this? BTW, the simples approach would be to do not really in the object body but rather provide some other methods which should be overridden.

Comment: DelayedInit can do this, but it's deprecated. It can't be too hard to make an abstract def though

Comment: The code in the body of an `object` is executed at the point when/where the object is first referenced. Methods in the object (i.e. `def`s) are defined but not invoked. An object that `extends App` has all of the body code wrapped in a `main()` method. It looks like what you want is going to be different depending on if the object extends `App` or not.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - just updated the question to provide more background.

Comment: @user agreed re: DelayedInit - I'm not read in on the whole story of why it's being deprecated and was wondering if there's another way to do this that I was missing

Comment: @six_minute_abs unless you want headaches and spent multiple times debugging and making your team mates hate you. Go with the first approach Dmytro showed. I will provide another approach which I believe will be more situated to your use case. But please, do not go with macros, not delayed init, the first one is not really straightforward and the second one can cause strange errors in runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard approach would be to run the code not in the body of an object but in some method

```
trait MyBeforeAndAfter {
  def before() = println("I am executed before!")
  def after() = println("I am executed after!")
  def run(): Unit

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    before()
    run()
    after()
  }
}


object MyApp extends MyBeforeAndAfter {
  override def run(): Unit = {
    println("I am generic code in the body that's wrapped")
  }
}
```

Then if you run `MyApp` it will print

```
I am executed before!
I am generic code in the body that's wrapped
I am executed after!
```

If you really want to run code in the body of an object you can define macro annotation

```
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

class beforeAndAfter extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro BeforeAndAfterMacro.impl
}

object BeforeAndAfterMacro {
  def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    annottees match {
      case q"$mods object $tname extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$body }" :: Nil =>
        val parents1 = parents :+ tq"MyBeforeAndAfter"
        q"""$mods object $tname extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents1 { $self =>
          def run(): Unit = {
            ..$body
          }
        }"""
      case _ =>
        c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "annottee must be an object")
    }
  }
}

@beforeAndAfter
object MyApp {
  println("I am generic code in the body that's wrapped")
}

//Warning:scalac: object MyApp extends scala.AnyRef with MyBeforeAndAfter {
//  def <init>() = {
//    super.<init>();
//    ()
//  };
//  def run(): Unit = println("I am generic code in the body that\'s wrapped")
//}
```

Comment: Accepting for the macro approach - I think this conclusively shows that yes - can be done via overrides or macros these approaches together answer the question "in a straightforward" (code for easy) part of my question. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `before` and `after` as functions and then invoke them in the `execute` method. The `execute` method is taking custom function as input, and executes in certain order. This is a standard approach which works irrespective of whether you call it in `main` or in another class.

```
trait BeforeAfter {
      def execute(myfunction : () => Unit) = {
        before()
        myfunction()
        after()
      }
      def before() = println("before")
      def after() = println("after")
    }
object MyApp extends App with BeforeAfter{
      def myprinter() = println("printing main")
      execute(myprinter)
    
    }
```

Results:

```
before
printing main
after
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I like the approach here - accepted Dmytro's per my comment on his

Answer (score 2):

Here a similar approach from the of @DmytroMitin
The only difference is that this lets you customize and reuse `before` and `foreach` methods.

```
trait BeforeAndAfter {
  def before(): Unit
  def after(): Unit
}

trait Program { self: BeforeAndAfter =>
  def run(args: List[String]): Unit
  
  final def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    self.before()
    run(args.toList)
    self.after()
  }
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
trait MyBeforeAndAfter extends BeforeAndAfter {
  override final def before(): Unit = {
    println("Setup")
  }
  
  override final def after(): Unit = {
    println("Clean up")
  }
}

object MyApp extends Program with MyBeforeAndAfter {
  override final def run(args: List[String]): Unit = {
    println("Program")
  }
}
```

You can see it running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/gUqAguomT4CMDsJws2Irkg).